# python .env change saves

Tags: python, environment-variables

I am making a username and password python thing and I was wondering how I would have my .env save its contents. Please put the edited code in the comments and describe what you changed. Thanks!

Code Follows:

```py
import os

os.environ['USER'] = 'admin'
os.environ['PASSWORD'] = 'admin'

print('Please Log In. admin Is The Defalt User And Password')
print('Username:')
inputed_username = input()

logged_username = os.getenv('USER')

if  inputed_username == logged_username :
  logged_password = os.environ.get('PASSWORD')
  print('Password:')
  inputed_password = input()
  if inputed_password == logged_password :
    print('Welcome ' + inputed_username + '!')
    while True :
      print('What Do You Want To Do?')
      print('''
    1: Change Username
    2: Change Password
    3: Log Out
      ''')
      ch1 = input()
      if ch1 == '1' :
        print('What Do You Want Your New Username To Be?')
        new_username = input()
        os.environ['USER'] = new_username
        
      if ch1 == '2' :
        print('What Do You Want Your New Password To Be?')
        new_password = input()
        os.environ['PASSWORD'] = new_password
        
      if ch1 == "3" :
        break
        
        
  else :
      print('WRONG PASSWORD')
else :
  print('WRONG USERNAME')
```

Comment: see https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: Oh, thx @balderman do you want to put that in answers so i can reward you?

Comment: Did you test it and find out that it works?

Comment: how would i set a base value in it?

Comment: what do you mean by "base value"? Did you look at my code below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am making a username and password python thing and I was wondering how I would have my .env save its contents

modify `os.environ` . See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ).

```
inputed_username = input()
os.environ['USER_NAME'] = inputed_username
```

Read from env

```
value = os.getenv('USER_NAME','admin')  # admin is the default
```